# Gnome Terminal not opening

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-terminal, desktop-shortcuts

When I try and open the gnome terminal, by clicking the 'terminal' icon in apps, I get a loading and then nothing happens. Is there some way of seeing the background output of trying to open it to try an ddebug it?

UPDATE 1:

So I was able to open xterminal and tried starting the gnome terminal like this: `gnome-terminal`

This resulted in this output, sorry if it is slightly wrong I had to manually copy it since I couldn't work out how to copy and paste in xterminal:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

UPDATE 2:

So I got it working again by using google fu to find [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180103) which got me to enter: `locale-gen` and reboot which seemed to fix it.

Comment: open another terminal (xterm, rxvt, ...) , and try to run gnome-terminal from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer) [suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311282/gnome-terminal-not-opening#comment547414_311282), if you can open another terminal, you can run `gnome-terminal` from there.

Alternatively, you can dump `gnome-terminal`'s output to a file: assuming you're running GNOME, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and enter

```
sh -c "gnome-terminal > ~/gnome-terminal.log 2>&1"
```

Then you'll find all the output in `~/gnome-terminal.log`.

Comment: Thanks this got me on the right path, because I was able to search the internet for the answer, since I had the error message

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 after installing Google Chrome gnome-terminal doesn't work. Wait to log and then timeout.

Please check - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1772259

Run in xterm or other terminal the following commands:

```
# This works for me
dbus-launch gnome-terminal

# Fix
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all
gnome-terminal &
```